# Runtime error 5 when I try to add a textbox to a powerpoint slide from excel using vba

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I need to add a textbox to a powerpoint slide from mac excel 2011. I'm attempting to use the PowerPoint.Slide.Shapes.AddTextbox function to do it.
The full error message I'm getting is:

```
Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument
```

The initial setup for exporting works fine, I've verified that all the variables are initialized/have data, and while I can get it to create a textbox on windows it simply doesn't work on mac. I've included all the reference libraries.

```
Dim ObjPPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ObjPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Public ObjSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Sub BtnExportTest_Click()
    ExportDataToPowerPoint
End Sub


Public Sub ExportDataToPowerPoint()
    ' Setup the new powerpoint.
    Set ObjPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set ObjPresentation = ObjPPT.Presentations.Add

    GenerateSlide
End Sub
```

Here is the code responsible for creating a slide.

```
' Generate the slides.
Private Sub GenerateSlide()
    ' Create new slide.
    Set ObjSlide = ObjPresentation.Slides.Add(ObjPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    ObjPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide ObjSlide.slideIndex

    ' Here we attempt to create a textbox for a title.
    setSlideTitle "Cogito Ergo Sum.", ObjSlide.slideIndex

    ....

End Sub
```

And here is the code for adding a text box to the slide.

```
' Places the title textbox at the top of the slide.
Sub setSlideTitle(titleText As String, activeSlideIndex As Integer)
    Dim slideW As Integer
    slideW = ObjPresentation.PageSetup.slideWidth - 100

    createSlideTextBoxOfSize titleText, activeSlideIndex, 50, 10, slideW, 64
End Sub

' Create a textbox on a slide with various criteria.
Sub createSlideTextBoxOfSize(textToShow As String, activeSlideIndex As Integer, leftDim As Integer, topDim As Integer, widthDim As Integer, heightDim As Integer)
    'Dim myTextBox As Shape
    Dim myTextBox As PowerPoint.Shape

    ' Create the textbox
    ' Failed attempts
    ' Set myTextBox = ObjSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 100, 100)
    ' ObjPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(activeSlideIndex).Shapes.AddTextbox(1, Left:=leftDim, Top:=topDim, Width:=widthDim, Height:=heightDim).Visible = msoCTrue

    With ObjPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(activeSlideIndex)
        ' Create the textbox
        ' More failed attempts.
        'Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=leftDim, Top:=topDim, Width:=widthDim, Height:=heightDim)
        'Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(1, leftDim, topDim, widthDim, heightDim)
        'Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(1, Left:=leftDim, Top:=topDim, Width:=widthDim, Height:=heightDim)
        'Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 100, 100, 400, 100)
        'Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, leftDim, topDim, widthDim, heightDim)
        'Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=leftDim, Top:=topDim, Width:=widthDim, Height:=heightDim)

        'This is the Error point; it works on windows, but not on mac.   <~~~~
        Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, leftDim, topDim, widthDim, heightDim)

        ' More unrelated formatting code.
        ...

    End With
End Sub
```

I've looked at every piece of documentation and sample code I could find, I've made sure the sheets and powerpoint are not in a protected state, and it is simply not working for mac excel 2011. Any help at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I ended up just creating a template file with premade slide layouts and then referencing them when I needed a slide of a particular type.

```
    ' Create new slide from a copy of the first slide in the powerppoint template file.
    ObjTemplatePresentation.Slides(slideIndexYouWantToCopy).Copy
    ' This is called to make sure it finishes coping the slide to the clipboard before we try and paste it.
    DoEvents
    ObjPresentation.Slides.Paste
```